# Can one define functions like in JavaScript?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, lambda

In Python, can one define a function (that can have statements in it, thus not a lambda) in a way similar to the following JavaScript example?

```
var func = function(param1, param2) {
    return param1*param2;
};
```

I ask, since I'd like to have a dictionary of functions, and I wouldn't want to first define all the functions, and then put them in a dictionary.

The reason I want a dictionary of functions is because I will have another function that takes another dictionary as parameter, loops through its keys, and if it finds a matching key in the first dictionary, calls the associated function with the value of the second dictionary as parameter. Like this:

```
def process_dict(d):
     for k, v in d.items():
         if k in function_dict:
             function_dict[k](v)
```

Maybe there is a more pythonic way to accomplish such a thing?

Comment: How complex your functions are? Your javascript example can be expressed with lambda in python: `lambda p1, p2: p1 * p2`

Comment: So you would need a statement inside an expression (dictionary literal/constructor)? It is not possible in Python.

Comment: @zch No, I'd just start with an empty dict, and then do variable assignments like in the javascript example, except the left hand side is `function_dict["key"]`.

Comment: @IvanNevostruev I think some of them are too complex (many branches) and lengthy to make them lambda statements, even though it maybe could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class (with static methods) instead of a dictionary to contain your functions.

```
class MyFuncs:

    @staticmethod
    def func(a, b):
        return a * b

    # ... define other functions
```

In Python 3, you don't actually need the `@staticmethod` since class methods are simple functions anyway.

Now to iterate:

```
def process_dict(d):
   for k, v in d.items():
       getattr(MyFuncs, k, lambda *x: None)(*v)
```

N.B. You could also use a module for your functions and use `import`.